# numberical implementation of linear regression with "loose variable"

Tags: regression, computational-statistics, numerics

I understand how to solve a linear system $X \beta = y$

the solution is

$\beta = (X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} y$

The problem is I could have an entry $\beta_i$ where it has no exposure in $X$. i.e. $X$ has a column of zero vectors.

I understand that means $\beta_i$ has infinite possible solutions. I don't really care. I just want to estimate the rest of $\beta$

How do I solve this issue? I guess I could reconstruct the matrix with those empty columns removed, but is there a computationally more efficient method?

I am programming in C++ so there isn't much of a choice. I have to do it step by step, not using any fancy stats libraries (I have access to basic linear algebra stuff though)...

Comment: Just drop that column.  Most software will do it automatically--and it's an extremely efficient operation, since you're just moving data around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I totally follow your question. However, in the case that you have a column of zero vectors in your design matrix, then your least squares solution won't work because $X$ is singular. One workaround would be to use a generalized inverse matrix. If you let $A^+$ denote the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, then you can estimate the coefficient vector as $\beta=(X^\top X)^+ X^\top y$. If we assume that the $j$th column of $X$ is a zero vector, then the resulting estimate of $\beta_j$ will be zero. However, all other entries will correspond to the LS solution where that column had been removed.

Comment: hi, computationally how do you compute for "Moore-Penrose inverse"? I am programming in C++ so I kind of need to know it step by step, not using any existing libraries...

Comment: It's construction is nontrivial. If you really want to do that, have a look at this: http://sourceware.org/ml/gsl-discuss/2008-q2/msg00013.html